# SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xfe'

Tags: python

Here is my code and it looks fine.

```
import ael

while True:
    cmd = input('AEL > ')
    result, error = ael.run(cmd)

    if error: print(error.as_string())
    else: print(result)
```

But whenever I run it, wether it's from PyCharm (my IDE) or from the terminal, I always get the following error:  `SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xfe' in file C:\Users\[...] on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details`

Here is what I have tried in an attempt to solve this issue:

- Adding `# coding=utf-8` at the start of the program
- Adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the start of the program

How would I solve this issue? Any potential solutions?

Comment: Are you running under Python 3? Cause Python 3 should default to interpreting as UTF-8, and this sounds like maybe you're running Python 2 (whether you realize it or not).

Comment: I am running python 3.10

Comment: Open your python script with Notepad++ and save it again with the encoding forced to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue seems to be a mix of Byte Order marks (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) and having the file encoded in a different character set.

Character sets can be a huge mess and there is only one solution: Keep everything UTF-8 all the time and it should work most of the times. If a file is not UTF-8, then use something like Notepad++ to convert it to one. Usually this fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This happens sometimes because the file does not include the *Byte Order Mark* - *BOM*. Using **IntelliJ IDEA** (or any other *JetBrains* IDE) I solved the problem by adding the BOM through the encoding menu on the left bottom corner of the window:

[image: Add BOM]

You can do the same with any text editor that supports adding and removing BOM.